# search for a subpath in all virtual hosts of apache

Tags: django, apache, reverse-proxy, redirect, http-redirect

I have a virtual hosts configured as follows

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName        my.pf2.org
    ProxyRequests     Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

    <Proxy http://my.pf2.org:9090/*>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass         /i2  http://my.pf2.org:9090/ nocanon
    ProxyPassReverse  /i2  http://my.pf2.org:9090/
</Virtualhost>

<Virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName        my.pf1.org
    ProxyRequests     Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

    <Proxy http://my.pf1.org:8080/*>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass         /i1  http://my.pf1.org:8080/ nocanon
    ProxyPassReverse  /i1  http://my.pf1.org:8080/
</Virtualhost>
```

I want a apache url to be the front and search a given subpath in all virtual hosts linearly. eg: if the url is http://apache.local.com/portfolio1 , It should look for portfolio1 in  http://my.pf1.org:9090/portfolio1 and if it doesn't exist try http://my.pf2.org:8080/portfolio1

I tried a python flask application and it does perform redirection very well, However I cant get it to act like a proxy(fixed url). Is there a standard way in which mapping can be handled in an application(like a django app) while apache url acts as the entry point?

Comment: The way your VirtualHosts are configured, only the first VirtualHost will ever be used.  Apache listens on port 80 in both, and ServerName is set at the same value for both.  VirtualHosts1, port 80, ServerName somedomain1.com, VirtualHost2, port 80, ServerName somedomain2.com.  Once that is fixed, you can start working on your redirects and proxy settings.  And ServerName is not an IP, give it a domain name.

Comment: And should we assume that you have two other VirtualHosts or some software that listens on port 8080 and 9090?  Because as presented, you only listen on port 80.

Comment: Yes some webservice is listening on the above ports.

Comment: Updated the config to correct values

Comment: Sorry I do not get it, you have nothing about apache.local.com in that config.  If you want to get to site 1, and if it does not work, go to site 2, that is an high availability configuration you are looking for.   You can configure that with a load balancer configuration in Apache.  And you set the priority of site 1 to 100%, so all traffic goes to site 1, unless it is down, so then it goes to site 2.